# What should we do with the vector tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

There are currently 45 questions tagged [vector](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector) on the main site. Most of these are about the typesetting vector, i.e. mathematical notation. Some of them however concerns vector graphics, or vectorized fonts, and there's one on drawing a vector with TikZ.

Is the tag even necessary? If so, which context should it be used for?

#### Update

I took the liberty of following Ryan's advice without further ado. I've edited the [tag wiki excerpt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112411/vector-wiki-excerpt), and I took a quick look through the questions to retag them where needed (as some of you perhaps noticed).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There seems to be a bit of a trend to have a tag named after "major" environments or macros/fonts/symbols/etc., which I suppose makes sense if the thing is complicated or subtle, or at least prone to error.  It actually seems that the concept of a "vector" as realized in TeX is such a thing: there are questions about vectors written as column vectors (matrices), as row vectors (tuples), or different vector styles, interaction with fonts or other packages...it seems worth having a tag.

Therefore, the *separate* topic of depicting vectors in TikZ or pstricks or so on is off-label and honestly, those should probably just have the tag removed and be left with just the package tag.

The *even more separate* topic concerning vector graphics or fonts is clearly a misinterpretation.  Probably, you can start by fixing the tag wiki to be more specific.  More drastically, there's possibly room for a tag called, say, [drawing-vectors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drawing-vectors) to absorb the second kind of question.  After which I suppose we would need a [vector-graphics](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vector-graphics) tag as well.  But (as I asked about in my recent question here) I don't know whether it's wise to go ahead and do that kind of retagging.

Comment: For non-package-specific questions about vector graphics one should use [tag:diagrams] (see its tag wiki excerpt).